# Custom values in xml

Tags: java, android, xml, preference

`res/xml/prefs.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <com.estysoft.android.preference.SeekBarPreference
            android:dialogMessage="Something duration" 
            android:key="duration" 
            android:summary="How long something will last" 
            android:text=" minutes" 
            android:min="5" 
            android:defaultValue="5" 
            android:max="60" 
            android:title="Duration of something"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

this is my problem is that android:min="5"  gives `error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'min' in package 'android'.`  How to give that minimum value to my custom SeekBarPreference?

edit, Im adding SeekBarPreference source to

```
package com.estysoft.android.preference;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.preference.DialogPreference;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;


public class SeekBarPreference extends DialogPreference implements
        SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
    private static final String androidns = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";

    private SeekBar mSeekBar;
    private TextView mSplashText, mValueText;
    private Context mContext;

    private String mDialogMessage, mSuffix;
    private int mDefault, mMax, mMin, mValue = 0;

    public SeekBarPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;

        mDialogMessage = attrs.getAttributeValue(androidns, "dialogMessage");
        mSuffix = attrs.getAttributeValue(androidns, "text");
        
        mMax = attrs.getAttributeIntValue(androidns, "max", 100);
        mMin = attrs.getAttributeIntValue(androidns, "min", 0);
        
        mDefault = attrs.getAttributeIntValue(androidns, "defaultValue", mMin);

    }

    @Override
    protected View onCreateDialogView() {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params;
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(mContext);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layout.setPadding(6, 6, 6, 6);

        mSplashText = new TextView(mContext);
        if (mDialogMessage != null)
            mSplashText.setText(mDialogMessage);
        layout.addView(mSplashText);

        mValueText = new TextView(mContext);
        mValueText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        mValueText.setTextSize(32);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layout.addView(mValueText, params);

        mSeekBar = new SeekBar(mContext);
        
        mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        layout.addView(mSeekBar, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        if (shouldPersist())
            mValue = getPersistedInt(mDefault);

        mSeekBar.setMax(mMax-mMin);
        mSeekBar.setProgress(mValue-mMin);
        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindDialogView(View v) {
        super.onBindDialogView(v);
        mSeekBar.setMax(mMax-mMin);
        mSeekBar.setProgress(mValue-mMin);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSetInitialValue(boolean restore, Object defaultValue) {
        super.onSetInitialValue(restore, defaultValue);
        if (restore)
            mValue = shouldPersist() ? getPersistedInt(mDefault) : 0;
        else
            mValue = (Integer) defaultValue;
    }

    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seek, int value, boolean fromTouch) {
        String t = String.valueOf(value+mMin);
        mValueText.setText(mSuffix == null ? t : t.concat(mSuffix));
        if (shouldPersist())
            persistInt(value);
        callChangeListener(new Integer(value));
    }

    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seek) {
    }

    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seek) {
    }

    public void setMax(int max) {
        mMax = max;
    }

    public int getMax() {
        return mMax;
    }

    public void setMin(int min) {
        mMin = min;
    }

    public int getMin() {
        return mMin;
    }

    public void setProgress(int progress) {
        mValue = progress;
        if (mSeekBar != null)
            mSeekBar.setProgress(progress-mMin);
    }

    public int getProgress() {
        return mMin + mValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you reading the xml file in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define custom xml attribute before using it.

In your `res/values/attrs.xml` file:

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="SeekBarPreferenceAttrs">
        <attr name="min" format="integer" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Comment: You have to define xml attribute before using it in xml.

Comment: i added `res/values/attrs.xml` but all is still the same